# Convert Three-Way to Single Switch and Add Smart Switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch

Would like some feedback/instruction on converting a three-way to single switch and then install a "smart" switch that requires LINE, LOAD & NEUTRAL.

Current Configuration:

( Switch A ) has (2) black wires and (1) red wire. + ground

```
BLACK silver screw                RED silver screw
      black screw               BLACK black screw
```

( Switch B ) has (1) black wire (1) red wire and (1) white wire. + ground

```
BLACK silver screw
WHITE black screw                RED silver screw
```

Have REMOVED BOTH SWITCHES and have capped off all of the wires.

With the BREAKER TURNED ON and the SWITCHES REMOVED:
.

( Switch A ) black wire that WAS connected on the bottom right black screw is HOT.

To clarify when the black wire is disconnected from the switch it is HOT.

When this same black wire is connected to the switch it is NOT HOT.

( Switch A ) red wire that was connected on the top right silver screw is HOT.

( Switch A ) black wire that was connected on the top left silver screw is COLD.
.

( Switch B ) black wire is HOT

( Switch B ) white wire is HOT [so this appears not to be neutral]???

( Switch B ) red wire is HOT.

.

The breaker feeds two other lights on different switches. These lights remain on with ( Switch A & Switch B ) removed.

There appears to be a NEUTRAL in both gang boxes.

Thanks for your time.

The first picture is ( Switch A ) [middle switch] is the one that is being replaced / removed.  (wires removed)

[image: Switch A]

The second picture is where ( Switch B ) was.

[image: Switch B]

The first switch, what remains of it, is ( Switch B )

[image: Switch B]

This is left side of ( Switch A )

[image: Switch A]

This is right side of ( Switch A )

[image: Switch A]

Clarification of when wires are hot or not:

When the BLACK wire is disconnected from the right bottom of ( Switch A ) it is HOT.

When this same BLACK wire is connected to the switch it is NOT HOT.

( Switch B ) has been removed and testing wires without connected to it.

When ( Switch A ) is in the ON position ( Switch B ) RED wire hot  BLACK wire cold WHITE wire hot

When ( Switch A ) is in the OFF position ( Switch B ) RED wire  cold BLACK wire cold  WHITE wire hot

Island Light Box Below

[image: Island Light Box]

IF cables are coming into the box from the direction of their associated switches then ( Switch B ) would be entering the box, out of view, at the top of photo and ( Switch A ) would be coming in at the back hole, in view.

3 Gang Box For kitchen recessed / kitchen island / mud room light

[image: 3 gang for kitchen]

The middle one is for the kitchen island light.  WHITE wires are nutted together, see behind switch.

Comment: You are on the right track looking at screw colors, but wire colors  don't mean much in 3-way circuits.  it's much more important what cables those wires are in, and what the *other* wires in those cables are doing.  . We need to know what else is going on in the box.  If able please shoot us pics of the inside of both boxes.

Comment: Also, is this a stairway? Are you sure the second switch location isn't required by Code?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes involved please? Also, where are these switch boxes located, and what do they control, as multi-location control is mandated by Code for some lighting outlets...

Comment: Not a stairway.  Its an kitchen island light.  Get this one switch is in the adjacent family room and the other switch is in the adjacent mudroom.

Comment: Also...is there another junction box somewhere in this mess? I see a...mismatched set of wires heading to the two switches that controlled this light...

Comment: With a "smart" switch and Alex it should elevate the awkwardness.  And the first gang box in the mudroom is a rats nest.

Comment: Which picture are you referring to? "mismatched set of wires" There is not another switch for the island light. However the breaker powers other lights.

Comment: Oh are you talking about the first switch in the first photo?  That controls the main kitchen lights and it is working.  It is a three-way.  The middle switch is the one I am working on at the moment.  It is the old "dumb" switch hanging down.

Comment: The 3 gang may have a neutral in the back I see a bunch of white, if nutted together they would be the neutral. What type or brand of smart switch?

Comment: @EdBeal Insteon 2477D

Comment: Ok last question , you want the smart switch at the 3 gang location and to remove the switch at the 2 gang location. If this is correct it can be done with the single throw smart switch.  Just want to make sure this is what you want before trying to think this morning.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the light these switches control, without unhooking any wires? With some clever rearranging, we can get you your multi-way control back using an Insteon remote at the other location...

Comment: Can you show us what the white wires from the two cables that connected to Switch A are doing?  I suspect they're nutted together in the back of the box, but can't make that wirenut out in the box-photo...too tangled up back there :/

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the breaker has at least  two other lights on it so the question is are they being feed from here or visa versa.  Purchased a couple of 2477D for $20 at Thanksgiving.  Now they cost more than double what I payed so I want to stick with what I have.

Comment: @IOwnIOweOhMy do keep them around, I'm sure you'll be able to find other places they are useful even if you can't use them for this specific light

Comment: As to your question, though, I'm pretty sure the box you opened connects to the switches (as it has an old-style switch loop coming from it -- I can tell because of the white nutted in with the blacks)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added photo of 3 Gang box with wires pulled out for better view.

Comment: Currently both switches have been removed and wires capped off.  Testing the wires now show that ( Switch A ) wires BLACK & RED on right side are HOT and that BLACK wire on left top COLD.  At ( Switch B ) location BLACK, RED & WHITE are all HOT.  Something seems wrong now as test do not seem to be what they were when I started.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102515/discussion-on-question-by-i-own-i-owe-oh-my-convert-three-way-to-single-switch-a).

Comment: Note that it's considered quite impolite around these parts to remove information from your question, as that makes it less useful to future viewers.  I reverted your last couple of edits as a result of this; in particular, was there a reason you went in and removed the pictures from your post?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes there was a reason.  And as I had stated the images would be returned once corrected.  The polite thing to have done would to have asked me prior to you doing what you did.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel One other thing since you have the power please delete the images from Imgur.  Once you have done that let me know and I will reload the corrected images.  Thank you for your time.  And please ASK BEFORE you do anything like that again as it really puts people off of even wanting to use a site like this.  I would have contacted you directly but all of your contact information is hidden.

Comment: @IOwnIOweOhMy -- deleting the images from the Stack Imgur is not a power I have, unfortunately :/

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the pictures are back.  Forgot to remove the META data and then just discovered that Imgur does it auto-magically.

Comment: @IOwnIOweOhMy -- ah, sorry about the confusion then; for future reference, if you need to replace something (like the pictures) in the post wholesale, it's best to get everything prepped offline then fix the post in a single edit (looks less screwy that way).  Glad things are all good now, though!

Answer (score 1):

### You don't have the neutral you think you do

This particular light was wired as a spurred three-way switch off of an old-style switch loop, so you actually do *not* have a neutral at *either* switch box, despite the white wires being present in both.  In your case, we can tell white is the *always-hot* wire at both switch locations, even, from the fact that it's the white wire nutted to the bundle of black wires in the light box.

From there, we know that the black wire in the cable from the light to switch A is the switched-hot, and that the black and red wires in the cable between switch A and switch B were the travellers in your old setup.  Since there's no neutral in all this, and the Insteon 2477D requires a neutral to work (i.e. power the smarts inside), we can't use that part here by itself.

### Never fear, though! Insteon to the rescue!

However, since you are working in the wonderfully flexible system that is Insteon, there *is* a way to get what you want, simply by adding some more parts. You will need an Insteon In-lineLinc™ Dimmer module (model 2475DA1) for this, in addition to the dimmers you already have.

Once you have the correct pieces for this job, you'll need to rewire things as follows, starting with the fixture box:

- All the fixture-box blacks get nutted to each other and to the in-line dimmer's black (LINE) wire (but not the fixture's black wire! otherwise, the light will simply be on all the time)
- All the fixture-box whites get nutted to each other, the in-line dimmer's white (NEUTRAL) wire, and the fixture's neutral wire
- The bare (GROUND) wire from the in-line dimmer gets nutted to the existing bare pigtail from the box and the fixture's bare ground wire
- The fixture's black wire, finally, gets nutted to the red (LOAD) wire from the in-line dimmer

At this point, we move on to the first switch box, where the dimmer that replaces switch A needs to be wired as a 3-way *secondary* controller:

- The two black wires that went to switch A get nutted to each other and to the black (LINE) wire on the first dimmer
- The two white wires associated with the switch A circuit that are nutted to each other need to have the white (NEUTRAL) wire from the first dimmer nutted in with them
- The bare ground wire that went to switch A needs to be nutted to the bare (GROUND) wire from the first dimmer
- The red wire that went to switch A and the red (LOAD) wire on the first dimmer both need to be capped off individually, as neither wire is used in this configuration

Now that we have switch A done, we can button up that switch box and move onto wiring switch B as an Insteon 3-way secondary as well:

- The black wire that went to switch B gets nutted to the black (LINE) wire on the second dimmer
- The white wire that went to switch B gets nutted to the white (NEUTRAL) wire on the second dimmer
- The bare ground wire that went to switch B gets nutted to the bare (GROUND) wire on the second dimmer
- And, finally, the red wire that went to switch B and the red (LOAD) wire on the second dimmer both need to be capped off individually, as again, neither wire is used in this configuration.

Now, you can button switch B's box up, turn the breaker on, and set to work configuring the Insteon links so that the two wall dimmers are linked to each other (in a 3-way cross-link) *and* to the in-line dimmer module (so that it can receive commands from both dimmers).  Once the Insteon links are configured, you can turn the breaker off again, put the ceiling fixture back up, turn the breaker on, and enjoy your multi-way dimming setup!

Comment: Really appreciate all of the information. Not exactly what I was wanting to do but will consider it.  If it makes a difference there is a non-hot NEUTRAL in the 3 gang. An Insteon dimmer controlling recessed lights is attached to it.  Any other option to do this with one switch at the 3 gang and remove the switch at the 2 gang.  Should I consider a new run of romex from 3 gang to fixture box.

Comment: @IOwnIOweOhMy that neutral can't be used because it's from the wrong cable (and perhaps even the wrong *circuit* altogether).  One could replace the 14/2 from the 3-gang to the fixture box with a 14/3 and bring neutral down that way, but it'd likely be more expensive to do that than to use the In-LineLinc.  (And the Insteon stuff is all capable of 3-way (or more!) control, you just need to use Insteon controllers at all locations, instead of mechanical switches)